# Mutable versions of cadr, caddr, etc

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

I'm wondering how to implement mutable versions of cadr, caddr, and the likes in Racket without defining each one separately? ie. not

```
(define (mcadr exp)
    (mcar (mcdr exp)))
```

It seems that for mutable lists or pairs, Racket only supports mcar and mcdr but not the "expanded" versions. Do I need to know and be good at macros to be able to do this?

Answer (score 10):

Here's a macro solution:

```
#lang racket/base

(require racket/mpair (for-syntax racket/base))

(define-syntax (define-combinations stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ n) (integer? (syntax-e #'n))
     (let ([n (syntax-e #'n)])
       (define options (list (cons "a" #'mcar) (cons "d" #'mcdr)))
       (define (add-options r)
         (apply append
                (map (λ (opt)
                       (map (λ (l) (cons (string-append (car opt) (car l))
                                         (list (cdr opt) (cdr l))))
                            r))
                     options)))
       (define combinations
         (cdddr
          (let loop ([n n] [r '(("" . x))])
            (if (zero? n) r (append r (loop (sub1 n) (add-options r)))))))
       (define (make-name combo)
         (let ([s (string->symbol (string-append "mc" (car combo) "r"))])
           (datum->syntax stx s stx)))
       (with-syntax ([(body ...) (map cdr combinations)]
                     [(name ...) (map make-name combinations)])
         #'(begin (define (name x) body) ...)))]))

(define-combinations 4)
(mcaddr (mlist 1 2 3 4 5))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
(define mcaar (compose mcar mcar))
(define mcadr (compose mcar mcdr))
;; ...
(define mcddddr (compose mcdr mcdr mcdr mcdr))
```

But there is no real getting around the repetition. Even in the Racket source (look in `racket/src/list.c`), the repetition is there, albeit prettified a little with C macros.

Comment: Yes, this is probably the sweet spot for solutions that don't involve macros.